# Pybrain - which weight belongs to which connection?

Tags: python, algorithm, neural-network

I'm having an issue with pybrain. I created a simple xor problem and used pybrain to solve it without using bias, and then used a simple algorithm to get all weights from one layer to the next. Everything is ok here, no need to know which weight belong to which connection.

The problem comes when I try to replicate the neural network in VHDL. I have tried using the weights in many combinations but wasn't successful in using them in the correct order (I initially thought that the problem was with the VHDL code, but then I tried doing the same manually, but ended up with the same result).

The network lookes like this

```
  c1/5-   O   c9- 
O c2/6-   O  c10-  O
O c3/7-   O  c11- 
  c4/8-   O  c12- 
in|hidden|out
```

the O are the neurons and the cN are the connections

And the obtained weights are as follows:

**in -> hidden0** => [-1.5370131   0.20571103 -0.55526946  2.24190836  1.25758021  0.0099828   3.41607776  3.60830287]

**hidden0 -> out** => [ 1.18471773 -2.20053965 -2.60886924  3.70095397]

I tried sing them in the 2 most obvious ways first:

```
    First combo|  Second combo

c1 -> -1.537     |     -1.53

c2 -> 0.206      |     1.257

c3 -> -0.555     |     0.205

c4 -> 2,242      |     0.0099

c5 -> 1.257      |     -0.555

c6 -> 0.0099     |     3.416

c7 -> 3.416      |     2.242

c8 -> 3.608      |     3.608

c9 -> 1.185      |     1.185

c10 -> -2.2      |     -2.2

c11 -> -2.609    |     -2.609

c12 -> 3.7       |     3.7
```

With both combos I got approximately the same result ~0.5.
Which means there's absolutely something wrong with the way I'm using the weights or the way I'm doing the math.

I'm doing the math the following way:

```
in -> hidden

suppose input "11"

1 * c1 + 1 * c2 = RES

output = sigmoid(RES)

1 * c3 + 1 * c4 = RES2

output2 = sigmoid(RES2)

and so on

hidden -> out

output * c9 = RES9

final = sigmoid(RES9)

output2 * c10 = RES10

final = sigmoid (RES10)

and so on
```

Now imagine I tried the other combination as well. The above combination is c1-c2 and the other combination is c1-c5

I implemented the same thing I did here in VHDL and the result was the same as the one I obtained manually.

I need the correct order of weights in order to validate my VHDL code. I know this is supposed to work because the result I get by running pybrain is:

[1, 0] [ 0.95923448]

[0, 1] [ 0.95626049]

[0, 0] [ 0.03813141]

[1, 1] [ 0.05266151]

PS : The xor I used is the one obtained in this [link](https://github.com/zonk1024/pybrain-xor-demo). I only modified the number of neurons in the hidden layer, modified the bias to False and used hiddenclass=SigmoidLayer. and the code obtained to get the weights can be either on of the following 2:

**first code**

```
for c in [connection for connections in net.connections.values() for connection in connections]:
print("{} -> {} => {}".format(c.inmod.name, c.outmod.name, c.params))
```

**second code**

```
for mod in net.modules:
    print("Module:", mod.name)
    if mod.paramdim > 0:
        print("--parameters:", mod.params)
    for conn in net.connections[mod]:
        print("-connection to", conn.outmod.name)
        if conn.paramdim > 0:
             print("- parameters", conn.params)
    if hasattr(net, "recurrentConns"):
        print("Recurrent connections")
        for conn in net.recurrentConns:
            print("-", conn.inmod.name, " to", conn.outmod.name)
            if conn.paramdim > 0:
                print("- parameters", conn.params)
```

Both these snippets were obtained from stackoverflow questions. If you want I can look for them and post the links here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer I was looking for.

The weights are side by side (c1-c2). 
Which means that the correct weights are:

```
c1 -> -1.537

c2 -> 0.206

c3 -> -0.555

c4 -> 2,242

c5 -> 1.257

c6 -> 0.0099

c7 -> 3.416

c8 -> 3.608

c9 -> 1.185

c10 -> -2.2

c11 -> -2.609

c12 -> 3.7
```

To get the correct order of weights do the following:

```
for c in [connection for connections in net.connections.values() for connection in connections]:
        print("{} -> {} => {}".format(c.inmod.name, c.outmod.name, c.params))
        print("org {}", reshape(c.params, (c.outdim, c.indim)))
```

The code to get the data is: 
**reshape(c.params, (c.outdim, c.indim))**
where "c" is a connection with the neuron.

The weights are given as follows:

```
[[-1.537   0.206],
 [-0.555   2.242],
 [1.257    0.0099],
 [3.416    3.608]]
```

and

```
 [[1.185],
  [-2.2],
  [-2.609], 
  [3.7]]
```

Each row are the connections to the neuron.

For example:

```
Suppose input = "10"
1 * -1.537 + 0 * 0.206 
and then goes to the sigmoid function
and so on
```

I had already tried this, but didn't work, wich makes sense because I was doing it wrong. When you create a new Network there are a few parameters that can be passed to it, hiddenclass and outclass are some of them. I set hiddenclass to SigmoidLayer, but I didn't initialize the outclass, which was initialized with its default value, LinearLayer. This means that I was doing an extra sigmoid function when I implemented the code in VHDL and when I tested it by doing the calculations by hand.

If you have more than 2 inputs connected to the hidden layer, suppose 4, it wuld look like this:

```
[[c1 c2 c3],
 [c4 c5 c6],
 [c7 c8 c9]]
```

And so on.

Good luck to anyone who needs this in the future